# Cambiar nombre columnas de manera masiva en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo la siguiente casuística, descargo datos en csv, estos datos son valores de índices para determinadas fechas, estos vienen acoplados a un id y una coordenada, de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que querría es lo siguiente, quedarme tan solo con la fecha por ejemplo del que se ve: 20180613
Eso básicamente, luego ya rizar el rizo sería extraer también los últimos 4 caracteres de NDVI que quede 20180613_NDVI, porque también tengo otros que son SAVI, pero vaya eso tampoco sería 100% necesario.

No pongo código pero quién quiera puedo pasarle los datos es un csv que pesa poquito.

Según he estado viendo creo que los tiros irían con las funciones sub y gsub, pero no consigo lo que quiero.

Agradecería mucho la ayuda que llevo dándole vueltas una semana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la función `substr` puedes extraer desde un inicio a fin de un determinado carácter.

Por ejemplo si el nombre de la columna esta en la posición 1, podemos trabajar con ella:

```
nombre_col_1 = names(df)[1]
```

Además la función `nchar` nos devuelve la cantidad de caracteres que contiene una cadena y la función `paste0` nos concatena distintas cadenas

Todo esto combinado:

```
nuevo_nombre = paste0(substr(nombre_col_1, 2, 9), # extraer del segundo digito al noveno
                      "_", # concatenarle un "_"
                      substr(nombre_col_1, nchar(nombre_col_1) - 3, nchar(nombre_col_1))) # Extraer desde el antepenúltimo al ultimo digito
```

Finalmente asignar esa cadena a la columna:

```
names(df)[1] = nuevo_nombre
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha solucionado completamente el problema